# All my programs closes after I close the laptop

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown

I use Ubuntu 18.04. When I close my laptop, and open it again, I find all my previously opened programs are lost. My Power configurations has "Off" in the "Automatic Suspend". Also, in "When the Power Button is pressed" I have "Off". But closing the laptop is not pressing the power button.

The lid close action seems to already be set to "suspend":

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
'suspend'
```

This is very annoying. I want to close my laptop (i.e., closed the screen. This is different from pressing the power button) and find all my previously opened programs.

Comment: what is your result of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action` and `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action`? Are they `logout` or `shutdown`?

Comment: The results for both commands are: 'suspend'

Comment: Also `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action`

Answer (score 2):

Note: Suspend works on RAM, therefore you should have enough RAM to sustain all your open apps otherwise 'suspend' won't work properly. See the output of `free m` with all the apps usually open when you 'suspend'.

1. Check System Settings > Power

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install pm-utils
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

2. If that doesn't  work:

   `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

and uncomment (remove "#") from the lines

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=suspend
```

Comment: It is already 'suspend' as you see in my comment in the OP.

Comment: @user9371654 `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action` is not there in "both" the commands by @Alvin Liang

Comment: I did all what you suggest. Still programs close when I close the laptop screen.

Comment: By "close the laptop screen" I assume you mean close the laptop lid. If not so please tell.

Comment: yes. This is what I mean.

Comment: [@user9371654](https://askubuntu.com/users/836841/user9371654) See my re-edited post.

Comment: if I close the led and open it in a short time, I find my programs. But if I left it for an hour or more, I lose them. It looks to me as if the hard disk shuts down after some time. I will try your suggestion and see.

Comment: Hard disk has to stop when suspended. Also check your RAM by Memory Test (memtest86+).